# How to split string in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas. I have data like this:

```
Category    Sales       Paid
Table       1 table     Yes
Chair       3chairs     Yes
Cushion     8 cushions  Yes
Table       3Tables     Yes
Chair       12 Chairs   No
Mats        12Mats      Yes
```

I have learnt how to apply a groupby on the `category` column
However, now I have multiple rows per group. I want to sum the number of sales per group held in the `Sales` column. But the sales number to add is written next to words e.g. 3Tables and there isn't a consistency on the way it's written as you can see above. How can I split the words and then capture the value and sum per group and print out?

My reading so far has signalled that I need to use an apply method, with lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get digits:

```
# Count all items
>>> (df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
                .groupby(df['Category']).sum())

Category
Chair      15
Cushion     8
Mats       12
Table       4
Name: Sales, dtype: int64

# Count only paid items
>>> (df['Sales'].where(df['Paid'] == 'Yes', other='0')
                .str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
                .groupby(df['Category']).sum())
Category
Chair       3
Cushion     8
Mats       12
Table       4
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

Intermediate results:

```
>>> df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
0     1
1     3
2     8
3     3
4    12
5    12
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

Comment: how would I remove NaN's from the values?

Comment: Why do you have NaN values? Use `.dropna()` if needed. Maybe you should provide an example.